# Run customised android monkey test from adb shell

Tags: android, monkeyrunner, adb, android-monkey, monkey-testing

I have written a monkey test .py file and I just want to run that file from "adb shell" rather then using monkeyrunner so is there any way to run monkey test python file from adb shell?

Below is the monkey --help section where I can see we can run scriptfile too

```
usage: monkey [-p ALLOWED_PACKAGE [-p ALLOWED_PACKAGE] ...]
              [-c MAIN_CATEGORY [-c MAIN_CATEGORY] ...]
              [--ignore-crashes] [--ignore-timeouts]
              [--ignore-security-exceptions]
              [--monitor-native-crashes] [--ignore-native-crashes]
              [--kill-process-after-error] [--hprof]
              [--match-description TEXT]
              [--pct-touch PERCENT] [--pct-motion PERCENT]
              [--pct-trackball PERCENT] [--pct-syskeys PERCENT]
              [--pct-nav PERCENT] [--pct-majornav PERCENT]
              [--pct-appswitch PERCENT] [--pct-flip PERCENT]
              [--pct-anyevent PERCENT] [--pct-pinchzoom PERCENT]
              [--pct-permission PERCENT]
              [--pkg-blacklist-file PACKAGE_BLACKLIST_FILE]
              [--pkg-whitelist-file PACKAGE_WHITELIST_FILE]
              [--wait-dbg] [--dbg-no-events]
              [--setup scriptfile] [-f scriptfile [-f scriptfile] ...] >> This might be helpful to run the file if i am not wrong
              [--port port]
              [-s SEED] [-v [-v] ...]
              [--throttle MILLISEC] [--randomize-throttle]
              [--profile-wait MILLISEC]
              [--device-sleep-time MILLISEC]
              [--randomize-script]
              [--script-log]
              [--bugreport]
              [--periodic-bugreport]
              [--permission-target-system]
              COUNT
```

I tried to run the file using command `adb shell monkey -f test_monkey.py`

but is showing error `** Error: Count not specified'`

Please suggest the right direction need to follow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`monkey` does not accept python scripts, as I may guess your intention was from the extension used.

The scripts are something like

```
type= raw events
count= 10
speed= 1.0
start data >>
captureDispatchPointer(5109520,5109520,0,230.75429,458.1814,0.20784314,0.06666667,0,0.0,0.0,65539,0)
captureDispatchKey(5113146,5113146,0,20,0,0,0,0)
captureDispatchFlip(true)
```

take a look at [MonkeySourceScript.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/android-4.2.2_r1/cmds/monkey/src/com/android/commands/monkey/MonkeySourceScript.java).

Besides that, `COUNT` is not optional, so you should at least specify `1`.